# Causality violation in Kerr metric

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, kerr-metric, closed-timelike-curve

my professor told me that in Kerr metric, there is a zone of causality violation around the ring singularity, but he was saying this in the context of $M^2>a^2$, does this also apply to the cases when $M^2< a^2$ and $M^2=a^2$?

Answer (score 0):

I will take Boyer-Lindquist coordinates and $G=1$. When talking about violation of causality in black holes, we are referencing the existence of closed timelike curves inside the event horizon of the black hole. In the case $M^2<a^2$ the answer to your question is *yes*, there are closed timelike curves, and causality is therefore violated. Here is a paper that shows thiss: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00759491. As for the extremal (i.e., $a^2=M^2$) case, I am not familiar with any formal proof. The usual proof your professor likely showed you for $M^2>a^2$  uses the fact that, if $r<0$ is such that $|r|<<a$ and $|r|<< M$, you end up with $g_{\varphi\varphi}|_{\theta=\pi/2}\approx a^2(1 + 2M/r)$ which is negative since $r<0$. I don't see why this proof would fail in the limit that $a\to M$, specially since causality can also be violated for $M^2<a^2$, as noted above. But I could be wrong, of course, as I don't recall any formal proof of this result.